# What's the difference between the Popular, Long and Short versions of the Mahā-Mṛtyunjaya Mantra in terms of usage, benefits and theology?

Tags: shiva, mantras

I have come across three variations of Mahā-Mṛtyunjaya Mantra. One is the Popular Version, then there is a Long Version and the other is called as the Short Version.

Here goes,

"Popular Version" of Mahā-Mṛtyunjaya Mantra:

> ॐ त्र्य॑म्बकं यजामहे सु॒गन्धिं॑ पुष्टि॒वर्ध॑नम् ।
> उ॒र्वा॒रु॒कमि॑व॒ बन्ध॑नान् मृ॒त्योर्मु॑क्षीय॒ माऽमृता॑॑त् ।।
>
> oṃ tryámbakaṃ yajāmahe sughandhíṃ puṣṭivardhánam ।
> urvārukam iva bandhánān mṛtyor mukṣīya māmṛtāt ॥

The longer version (संपूर्ण मंत्र), annotates one line each both in the beginning and the end of the Popular Version:

> ॐ हौं जूं सः ॐ भूर्भुवः स्वः। 
> ॐ त्र्य॑म्बकं यजामहे सु॒गन्धिं॑ पुष्टि॒वर्ध॑नम् ।
> उ॒र्वा॒रु॒कमि॑व॒ बन्ध॑नान् मृ॒त्योर्मु॑क्षीय॒ माऽमृता॑॑त् ।
> ॐ स्वः भुवः भूः ॐ सः जूं हौं ॐ ।
>
> oṃ hauṃ jūṃ saḥ oṃ bhūrbhuvaḥ svaḥ ।
> oṃ tryámbakaṃ yajāmahe sughandhíṃ puṣṭivardhánam ।
> urvārukam iva bandhánān mṛtyor mukṣīya māmṛtāt ।
> oṃ svaḥ bhuvaḥ bhūḥ oṃ saḥ jūṃ hauṃ ।

There's another version called the Short Mṛtyunjaya Mantra (लघु मृत्युंजय मंत्र):

> ॐ जूं स माम् पालय पालय स: जूं ॐ ।
>
> oṃ jūṃ sa mām pālaya pālaya sa: jūṃ oṃ ।

Question - Please provide the scriptural references for all the three versions of the Mantra, which scriptures have these? Furthermore, please explain the difference in usages of these three versions in terms of theology, benefits, and associated rituals.

Comment: हौं is not a sanskrit, it sounds hindi. Neither is जूं, which also sounds hindi. The only correct vedic mantra is the first one. The next two mantras have added hindi words.

Comment: I don't if it's Sanskrit or not @Ikshvaku, but these mantras are a popular internet savoury and also recommended by several astrologers that I know. For ex:  [see here](https://m.jagran.com/lite/spiritual/puja-path-mahamrityunjaya-mantra-meaning-jaap-vidhi-benefits-and-importance-20746406.html)

Comment: Haum is Shiva Bija. Jum is also a Tantric Bija. Not Sanskrit?? @Ikshvaku

Comment: You can see how Shiva Bija (Haum) is revealed in a hidden code (in Sanskrit) in this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/30298/4732 @Ikshvaku

Comment: @Rickross Ok, I didn't know these were beeja mantras.

Comment: For general look: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18185/20129

Comment: @Rickross is right. These are Bija mantras.

Comment: @Ikshvaku - They are primordial Sanskrit sounds. Om Swami has elaborated much on this subject in his "The Ancient Science of Mantras". He talks exclusively about seeded and seedless mantras (they work pretty similar to seeded fruits and seedless fruits).

Comment: The "popular" version of Mrityunjaya Mantra cited here is actually Tryambaka mantra mentioned in Sharadatilaka & Brihat Tantrasara. The Mrityunjaya mantra, according to the Brihat Tantrasara, consists of the first 3 letters of the "short" version cited here. However the same text cites a "Shukropasita Mrityunjaya mantra" created by combing the words of the Gayatri mantra & Tryambaka mantra.

Comment: @Tezz : Please have a look at this question. Since you're quite knowledgeable in the MahAdeva-related stuff. See if you might have something on this. :))

Comment: There is one more version. You can add that as well. After the usual mrityunjaya mantra, it contains येते सहस्र मयुतं पाशा.....

Comment: Well, yes, @LSSJBroly  At the time, when I posted this question, I wasn't aware of all of those, but now, as it turns out, I know that there are at least 27 different types or variations of the Mahā-Mṛtyunjaya Mantra, starting from the Ekākṣarī = `हौं `, up to the Sahastrākṣara Mrityunjaya Mālā Mantra (consisting of 1000 words). So, just like the Lord, the variations of the _Mrityunjaya-mantra_ are endless. :)

Comment: Ohh..I wasn't knowing about 27 of them.. :O BTW were you able to find something related to your another question on mrityunjaya mantra in which you were asking about mrityunjaya mantra for different deities. I have seen that today and upvoted it too...tbh that was a very good question IMO. :D

Comment: Haha, thanks @LSSJBroly , about the Mritunjaya Mantra for other deities, I think they cannot be called Mritunjaya Mantra if they are for deities other than Shiva. Although, the closest I came across was for Dhanvantari.

Answer (score 3):

Although I ignored the question initially, the extended mantra contained something that caught my attention. so here is a partial answer.

If you look at the structure of mantra properly:

> ॐ हौं जूं सः ॐ भूर्भुवः स्वः।
> ॐ त्र्य॑म्बकं यजामहे सु॒गन्धिं॑ पुष्टि॒वर्ध॑नम् ।
> उ॒र्वा॒रु॒कमि॑व॒ बन्ध॑नान् मृ॒त्योर्मु॑क्षीय॒ माऽमृता॑॑त् ।
> ॐ स्वः भुवः भूः ॐ सः जूं हौं ॐ

We can separate it in three components:
The first,

> ॐ हौं जूं सः ॐ भूर्भुवः स्वः ।

The second,

> **ॐ** त्र्य॑म्बकं यजामहे सु॒गन्धिं॑ पुष्टि॒वर्ध॑नम् ।
> उ॒र्वा॒रु॒कमि॑व॒ बन्ध॑नान् मृ॒त्योर्मु॑क्षीय॒ माऽमृता॑॑त् । **ॐ**

The third,

> स्वः भुवः भूः ॐ सः जूं हौं ॐ

Looking properly, the second component is just your regular mantra. However, the first and the second are entirely made of *Beeja*. If you notice, then you might realize that the third line is an exact reverse of the first line. This is not done arbitrarily, it is called *Samput-Mantra*. (An Anulom-Vilom Samput)

Understand the first one to be in order- the *Anulom* (अनुलोम). The third component is in reverse order- the *Vilom* (विलोम). They close the middle mantra which is *Nama*. In the **AnnaAdiKalpa Tantra, 18-th Ulhassa**:

> स्तम्भे मृत्युज्नये इच्छेद्रक्षा दिषु च सम्पुटम्‌ ॥
> नाम्न आदो अनुलोमेन अन्ते विलोमक्रमेण इति भाव: ॥८॥

> The mantras are called **Samput** (सम्पुट), if its beginning has a **Anulom** and the end a **vilom**. These are used for *Stambhan* (placing a Stop), *Mrityu-Nivaran* (escaping a event of death) and *Rakshan* (protections).

The tantra also explains how to recite them:

> मन्त्रमादो वदेत्‌ सर्व साध्यसंज्ञामनन्तरम्‌ ।
> विपरीत पुनश्चान्ते सम्पुर्ट तत्‌ स्मृतं बुघेः ॥ ९ ॥

> First read the mantra in *Anulom* after which take the corresponding name, after which pronounce the mantra in reverse order. This is *Samput-Mantra*

The extended version is an *Samput* mantra. The shorter version (Laghu-Mṛtyunjaya Mantra) is also of *Samput* class. Its use and benifits are out of scope of my reading.

Take a look again, at those 'om' that are bolded. The first one is the *Pranav*, placed to activate or make mantra alive. But there is one more, actually placed at the very end of Mrituyjay-Mantra. This has another significance:

> तारान्त्याग्निविषप्राये मंत्र आग्नेय उच्येत।

> A 'om' placed at the end of mantra, makes it of *Agneya* class.

Comment: What's Agneya class mantras?

Comment: Placing om at the end of any mantra makes it Agneya. For e.g. Placing om at the end of Gayatri makes it Agneya. Now what's are its effects are it becomes eligible for some other karmas. Similar to the way we place Swaha at the end of mantra during homam. @vivikta