# Are there any mantras similar to the Mahā-Mṛtyunjaya Mantra, but dedicated to deities other than Rudra (Śhiva)?

Tags: shiva, gods, mantras

The [Mahā-Mṛtyunjaya Mantra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46440/whats-the-difference-between-the-popular-long-and-short-versions-of-the-mah%C4%81-m) is one of most famous mantra, said to provide immediate protection to the devotee from death and other problems, and ultimately [bestow Moksha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/i-want-to-know-the-exact-explanation-of-maha-mrityunjaya-mantra/18185#18185) to the chanter, if chanted properly.

My question is - If similar kind of Mantras exists for deities other than Śhiva (Rudra) too, which are said to bestow exactly similar benefits like the Mahā-Mṛtyunjaya Mantra? If yes, please provide references.

I ask this because just like there are several Sahasranāma and Gîtās dedicated to almost all major deities, however for both, the Viṣhṇu Sahasranāmam and the Śhrīmad BhāgavataGītā of the Mahābhārata, remains the most popular recensions in the "mass imagination", so similar thing might be possible for the Mahā-Mṛtyunjaya Mantra too, maybe?